Jacobian of the normalization of vector x, with respect to vector x.
Let $\mathbf{x}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times N}$ be a row vector of interest, and let $\mathbf{y}$ $=$ $||\mathbf{x}||^{-1} \mathbf{x}$ denote the normalization of $\mathbf{x}$ by the Euclidean / Frobenius norm.
I want to determine the gradient of $\mathbf{y}$ with respect to $\mathbf{x}$, via the Jacobian: $\frac{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{y})}{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{x})} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ .
I saw this older stackexchange post that generalizes to matrices, and note that this transformation is equivalent to the norm-normalization when $\mathbf{X}$ is a vector instead of a matrix.
Using greg's answer in that post, I obtain:

Now I feel pretty confident in this answer, but it would be nice to have it verified. I was unable to find a recourse that discussed this Jacobian, or the Jacobian of the inverse norm of the vector.

$\def\vec{\operatorname{vec}}$
$\def\qty#1{\left( #1 \right)}$
$\def\d{{\sf d}}$
There is no need to write the Jacobian matrix as $\frac{\partial \vec {\bf y}}{\partial \vec {\bf x}}$ since both $\bf y$ and $\bf x$ are vectors.
Start by writing
$$
{\bf y} = \lVert {\bf x} \rVert^{-1} {\bf x}
$$
in terms of vector components given a basis:
$$
y_i = \qty{x^j x_j}^{-\frac{1}{2}} x_i.
$$
Next apply the differential operator
\begin{align}
\d y_i & = \qty{x^j x_j}^{-\frac{1}{2}} \d x_i
-
\frac{1}{2} \qty{x^j x_j}^{-\frac{3}{2}} \qty{\d\qty{x^kx_k}} x_i \\
& = \qty{x^j x_j}^{-\frac{1}{2}} \delta^k_i \d x_k
-
\frac{1}{2} \qty{x^j x_j}^{-\frac{3}{2}} \qty{x^k \d x_k + \qty{\d x^k} x_k } x_i \\
&  = \qty{x^j x_j}^{-\frac{1}{2}} \delta^k_i \d x_k
-
\frac{1}{2} \qty{x^j x_j}^{-\frac{3}{2}} \qty{2 x^k \d x_k  } x_i \\
& = \qty{x^j x_j}^{-\frac{1}{2}} \delta^k_i \d x_k
-
\qty{x^j x_j}^{-\frac{3}{2}} \qty{ x^k \d x_k  } x_i
\end{align}
Therefore the partial derivative is
$$
\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x^k} = \lVert {\bf x} \rVert^{-1} \delta^k_i
- \lVert {\bf x} \rVert^{-3} x_i x^k
$$
or using invariants
$$
\frac{\partial {\bf y}}{\partial {\bf x}^\intercal} =
\lVert {\bf x} \rVert^{-1} {\bf I}
-
\lVert {\bf x} \rVert^{-3} {\bf x} {\bf x}^\intercal
$$

Using product differential rule:
$$
d\frac{\textbf{x}}{\sqrt{\langle \textbf{x}, \textbf{x} \rangle}}=\frac{d\textbf{x}}{\sqrt{\langle \textbf{x}, \textbf{x} \rangle}}
+
\textbf{x}\:d\frac{1}{\sqrt{\langle \textbf{x}, \textbf{x} \rangle}}
$$
More precisely on the second term:
$$
d\frac{1}{\sqrt{\langle \textbf{x}, \textbf{x} \rangle}}=
d\langle \textbf{x}, \textbf{x}\rangle^{-\frac12}=
-\frac{1}{2}\langle \textbf{x}, \textbf{x} \rangle^{-\frac32}d\langle \textbf{x},\textbf{x}\rangle=
$$
$$
=-\frac{1}{2}\langle \textbf{x}, \textbf{x} \rangle^{-\frac32}\langle 2\textbf{x},d\textbf{x}\rangle=
-\langle \textbf{x}, \textbf{x} \rangle^{-\frac32}\langle \textbf{x},d\textbf{x}\rangle=
-\frac{\langle \textbf{x},d\textbf{x}\rangle}{\|\textbf{x}\|^3}
$$
Now everything together:
$$
d\frac{\textbf{x}}{\sqrt{\langle \textbf{x}, \textbf{x} \rangle}}=\frac{d\textbf{x}}{\sqrt{\langle \textbf{x}, \textbf{x} \rangle}}
-\textbf{x}\frac{\langle \textbf{x},d\textbf{x}\rangle}{\|\textbf{x}\|^3}=
\frac{d\textbf{x}}{\|\textbf{x}\|}
-\frac{\textbf{x}\textbf{x}^\top d\textbf{x}}{\|\textbf{x}\|^3}=
$$
$$
=\left[\frac{1}{\|\textbf{x}\|}I_n -\frac{1}{\|\textbf{x}\|^3}\textbf{x}\textbf{x}^\top\right]d\textbf{x}
$$

A less mechanical approach to the problem is to construct a formula for the Jacobian by determining its eigendecomposition without constructing the matrix itself.
Let $f(x) = \|x\|^{-1}x$, then

$D_{x}f(x) = 0$, where $D_x$ is the directional derivative in the $x$ direction.
If $y\perp x$, then $D_yf(x) = y/\|x\|$. To see this, notice that $$\frac{x+hy}{\|x+hy\|} = \frac{x+hy}{\sqrt{\|x\|^2+h^2\|y\|^2}} = f(x) + h \frac{y}{\|x\|} + O(h^2).$$

Let $J(x)$ denote the Jacobian of $f$. We have now shown that $J(x)x = 0$ and $J(x)y = \|x\|^{-1}y$ for $y\perp x$. This implies two things:

$J(x)$ has an orthonormal diagonalizing basis $\{x/\|x\|,y_2,\dots,y_n\}$, where the $y_k$'s complete an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Hence, $J(x)$ is symmetric.

$\|x\| J(x)$ is an orthogonal projector onto the orthogonal compliment of $\mathrm{span}\{x\}$.


We are now done and can explicitly write
$$
J(x) = \frac{1}{\|x\|}P_{x^\perp} = \frac{1}{\|x\|}\left(I - \frac{xx^T}{\|x\|^2}\right).
$$

$
\def\b#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\ll#1{\l^{#1}}
\def\lR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\bR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\CR#1{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Let $\l$ denote the length of the $x$ vector, and differentiate it
$$\eqalign{
\ll2 &= x^Tx \qiq 2\l\,d\l=2x^Tdx \qiq d\l=\ll{-1}x^Tdx \\
}$$
Use this result to differentiate the vector of interest
$$\eqalign{
y &= \ll{-1}x \\
dy &= \ll{-1}dx \;+\; x\,d\ll{-1} \\
 &= \ll{-1}I\,dx \;-\; x\ll{-2}\,\c{d\l} \\
 &= \ll{-1}I\,dx \;-\; x\ll{-2}\,\c{\ll{-1}x^Tdx} \\
 &= \ll{-1}\LR{I-\b{\ll{-2}xx^T}}dx \\
 &= \ll{-1}\LR{I-\b{yy^T}}dx \\
\grad yx
 &= \ll{-1}\LR{I-yy^T} \\
}$$
$\sf NB\!:$ I used column vectors instead of row vectors, so you'll want to switch $\,y^T\!\!\iff\!y$
